# Invoking/Multithreading help wanted

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I have done my research but I am new to coding so I would like some help on how to implement the invoke on a control. I will provide my code below. For some reason it don't matter what you put in boxes it will still log you in and show you the mainmenu too

Basically I would like someone to explain how you would go about doing this to me. I am not wanting no free code handouts or anything I do want step by step instructions.

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    If username.Text = "" Or password.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please enter a Username and Password")
    Else
        'Connect to Database
        Dim connect As New MySqlConnection("server=server;user id=root;Password=root;database=member")

        connect.Open()

        'SQL Query to Get the Details

        Dim myAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim sqlquery = "Select * From User where username = '" + username.Text + "' And password = '" + password.Text + "'"
        Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand
        myCommand.Connection = connect
        myCommand.CommandText = sqlquery


        'Starting The Query
        myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand
        Dim mydata As MySqlDataReader
        mydata = myCommand.ExecuteReader

        'To check the Username and password and to validate the login 
        If mydata.HasRows = 0 Then
            BonfireAlertBox2.Visible = True
        Else

        End If

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Backgroundworker1_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    BonfireAlertBox1.Visible = True
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
    mainmenu.Show()
End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do `BonfireAlertBox2.Visible = True` in a background thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>***`Code reviews are off-topic for stack overflow.  In the future read the FAQ.`***</sup>

**[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms123401.aspx) is your friend.**

[BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation

> Occurs when the background operation has completed, has been canceled, or has raised an exception.

This means that the `RunWorkerCompleted` event will run once the background work is complete - no matter if it completes normally, by throwing an exception, cancelled by the user, or your basement floods.

---

[Parameterize your sql queries](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=parameterized%20sql%20query%20c%23&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) to protect against [Sql Injection Attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

---

[SqlDataReader.HasRows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.hasrows(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a Boolean, not an Integer.
Zero is `False`, so `If mydata.HasRows = 0 Then` is basically `If mydata.HasRows = False Then`.
*Is this what you intended?*